# "Runtime Error: working outside of application context" when trying to instantiate WTForms object in Flask view

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

So i have a form defined like this:

```
class NewDashForm(Form):
    tabname = StringField('tabname', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(1,16)])
    title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(1,128)])
```

And I am importing it in my views.py file, but when I try to instantiate it like this:

```
form = NewDashForm()
```

I get the "working outside of application context" error.  The application is generated by a "factory" method, like this:

```
def generate_application(config=None):
   application = Flask(__name__)
   application.config.from_object(config)
   application.register_blueprint(cheda.generate_blueprint(application.config,application.db))
   return application
```

There is some db related stuff that I left out in this last code snippet, but you get the idea.  From my understanding, anything that happens from within a view should automatically be under application context, but clearly I am missing something.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/bin/cheda-run", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cheda==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'cheda-run')()
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 546, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2666, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2339, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/code/cheda/cheda/cmd/run.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .. import application
  File "/code/cheda/cheda/application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .blueprints import cheda
  File "/code/cheda/cheda/blueprints/cheda.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..views import views as cheda_views
  File "/code/cheda/cheda/views/views.py", line 37, in <module>
    class NewDash(JsonApiView):
  File "/code/cheda/cheda/views/views.py", line 39, in NewDash
    form = NewDashForm()
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 212, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 68, in __init__
    csrf_enabled = current_app.config.get('WTF_CSRF_ENABLED', True)
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/vagrant/venv/cheda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only instantiate forms within view fuctions, doing so outside a request doesn't make sense.  You are getting the error because it's trying to get data from the request, which isn't present.

If you *really* need to instantiate it before hand, either pass empty data to it so it doesn't look at the request, or use a request context.

```
from werkzeug.datastructrues import MultiDict
form = MyForm(MultiDict())

# or

with app.test_request_context():
    form = MyForm()
```

Again, you should never be doing this in your application, a form is only useful inside a view during a request. The test request context would be useful if you wanted to test the form in a unit test.